# Mule4 time format

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-el

I am facing issue while doing string to time conversion in DataWeave2.0.

I am having string as "1800", my requirement is to convert it into time in HH:MM:SS format. I tried going through Mule docs on DateTime, Time but not able to convert string to Time in required format.

Comment: Need more information on what "1800" will resolve to. Should it be "18:00:00" or maybe "00:30:00"? Also what have you tried? What was the result? Please see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be resolved to 18:00:00. I tried with  LocalTime {format: "HHmm"} as String {format: "HH:mm:ss"}. Which didn't worked. Another option I can think of is String manipulation but it will only produces the string output.

Answer (score 2):

Since it doesn't have a time zone it's a LocalTime so you can try:

```
"1800" as LocalTime {format: "HHmm"} as String {format: "HH:mm:ss"}
```

Comment: Hi, tried with the option you mentioned but it is not yielding the expected result in dwl2.0

Comment: Hi Shoki, solution you provided is working. Issue is with the values I am getting from the target system is in integer, so I did convert it and then tried with your suggestion. It worked!